# how to add div element in HTML from json?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a html page. i want to add a div section in this html page form a json.

my json data is

```
var json = {
             "nodeName":"DIV",
             "nodeType":1,
             "id":"start",
             "children": [ 
                           {
                             "nodeName":"DIV",
                             "nodeType":1,
                             "children":[ 
                                         {
                                          "nodeName":"BUTTON", 
                                          "nodeType":1, 
                                          "id":"input_2", 
                                          "children":[]
                                         }
                              ]
                            }
              ]
            };
```

my complete code is

```
<html>
<body>
    <h1>javascript </h1>
    <div>
        <button onclick="call()">
                click
            </button>
    </div>        
<script>

        var c=1;
        var tempnode;
        var xbody = document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0];
        var json={"nodeName":"DIV","nodeType":1,"id":"start","children":[{"nodeName":"DIV","nodeType":1,"children":[{"nodeName":"BUTTON","nodeType":1,"id":"input_2","children":[]}]}]};
        function message_received(event) 
        {

        }
        function call()
        {

            traverse(json,"");
        }

        function traverse(num,parent) 
        {
            var c=1;
            console.log("start"+num+" parent "+parent);
            var lstnode=0;
            var node;
            var count=Object.keys(num).length;
            for (var i in num) 
            {
                c++;
                lstnode++;
                var count=Object.keys(num).length;
                console.log("jsonlenght:-"+count);
                console.log("lstnode "+lstnode);
                console.log(i, num[i]);

                if(num[i] !== null && typeof(num[i])=="object")
                {
                    console.log("object found");
                    console.log(num[i]);
                    console.log(node);
                    console.log("parent"+parent);
                    if(typeof node == 'undefined')
                        node=parent;

                    traverse(num[i],node);

                }
                else
                {
                    if(i=="nodeName")
                    {
                        node = document.createElement(num[i]);
                        console.log("nodeName:-"+c+node.innerHTML);
                    }
                    else if(i=="nodeType")
                    {
                        node.nodeType=num[i];
                        console.log("nodeType:-"+c+node);
                    }
                    else if(i=="id")
                    {
                        node.id=num[i];
                        console.log("id:-"+c+node);

                    }

                    if(lstnode==count && lstnode!=1)
                    {
                        if(parent=="")
                        {
                            document.body.appendChild(node);
                            console.log(node);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            parent.appendChild(node);
                            console.log(node);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you try coding with DOM, like with document...innerHTML? Sample link @ https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp . You have to add texts onto your web page, basically. But show your effort in this community.